# How to retrieve multiple data from file_get_html() function?

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I am trying to retrieve data from file_get_html($url).

```
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach ($html->find("h1") as $key => $value){
echo $value."<br>";
}
foreach($html->$find("p") as $key => $edu){
echo $edu;
}
```

I am trying to fetch more than one value from the url. But I get this error message. I get the result for **$value** , but I get error with the next one.

> Notice: Undefined variable: find in ...\parse.php on
>   line 18
>
> Fatal error: Method name must be a string in
>   ...\parse.php on line 18

This is line 18

> foreach($html->$find("p") as $key => $edu){

EDIT: Database Issue

```
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach ($html->find("span[class=full-name]") as $key => $name){

echo $name."<br>";
}
```

Database looks like:

> **< span class="first-name" >**  Tony Stark

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO personal (name) VALUES ('$name')");
if (!$result){
    echo "Error!<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using $html->$find("p") which in your case, `find()` is a method, but you treat it as a variable.

Try `$html->find("p")`

Hope it helps!
Keep on coding!
Ares.

Comment: Ohh damn! A serious typing mistake and a serious negligence mistake. Thanks a lot, Ares.

Comment: One more query Ares, how do I use span class="xyz" in find method?
syntax would be find(".'span class="xyz"'.") ???

Comment: I don't understand the question. please rephrase

Comment: You might be looking for something like this `$html->find("span[class=xyz]")` ??

Comment: In $html->find(), I would like to find this 'span class="college"'. How to write a proper syntax in html->find("  ").

Comment: try the above line. Insted of xyz replace with college

Comment: P.S: Here is a reference to that - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: Yes. Looking for the same. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem at all. Glad to be of help! ;)

Comment: Hey, Ares! My code worked, however when the data is stored in database, the data looks like "<span class="name"> Tony Stark". I am getting that extra span tag. How to remove that?

Comment: use regex to match everything until ' ' (space) or until '>' and then choose only the name from the $matches array 

Alternatively, you can use trim() function in php if the syntax will forever be the same. Documentation here: http://php.net/manual/ro/function.trim.php

Comment: But when I print $name, it prints without span tag

Comment: please provide a copy-paste of the code (including the print)

Comment: Try to update the database after you echo the name, to make sure that you have the same value. It could very be that the $name var gets rewritten when you try to add it in the DB

Comment: No changes. Same output

Comment: Sorry but without debug or an extensive look at your code I cannot replicate the issue to see exactly what happens ...